# Which stack-exchange site can you ask questions about Admob

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I recently created an Admob account and I am promoting my app. However I am really confuse and have a few questions. Where may I ask these kinds of questions?

Comment: What **kind** of questions about Admob?

Comment: @Oded A question about promoting my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of a single Stack Exchange site that would be suitable for questions about promoting your software.

There is a [marketing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51786/marketing) proposal on area51 that may be what you are looking for, but it is still a ways to go before going beta.

Comment: Is there another site where I may ask this question?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique - I am sure there is, just not on the Stack Exchange network. Good luck.